# reverse geo coding - Mapquest vs Overpass

Tags: mapquest

I'm looking for some c# sample code for reverse geo coding with skobbler, all I can find is offline examples

I need this to test the difference between Mapquest API reverse geo coding and and Overpass-Api.de

Does anyone know if they use exactly the same data?
If not, how do they compare (where are they getting their data from?)

Mapquest recently dropped their free quota so much, its not even working on the dev system, so I would like to look at a local implementation of Overpass API

Comment: It would be best to post this question to the [GIS stackexchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69007/openstreetmaps-api). I'm investigating these services, and [nominatim](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/), myself as well (results from the [beta opencagedata geocoder](http://geocoder.opencagedata.com/api.html#quickstart) fail to find results for "Barcelona Spain" but does work in my limited testing of reverse geocoding). Because MapQuest has a commercial terms and pricing I'd be inclined to use their services with expectations of and SLA with higher scale.